# How do I add the hash of a file to file itself

Tags: hashsum

I am trying to follow procedures at

[How To Create Your Own Odin Flashable TAR or TAR.MD5](http://www.rwilco12.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=92)

And the command `md5sum -t your_odin_package.tar >> your_odin_package.tar` does not work for me. That is, when I try to validate that I have a authenticated file, I get an error.

```
md5sum -t your_odin_package.tar >> your_odin_package.tar
```

Should I be doing this differently? I tried to use the file on the phone, and I got an error about authentication not working also.

I tried this also:

```
tar -H ustar -c aboot.mbn sbl1.mbn rpm.mbn tz.mbn sdi.mbn NON-HLOS.bin boot.img recovery.img system.img.ext4 cache.img.ext4 modem.bin >     N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar
sansari@ubuntu:~/stock3$ mv N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.$(md5sum  abc.tar | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
md5sum: abc.tar: No such file or directory
sansari@ubuntu:~/stock3$ mv N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar    N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar.$(md5sum   N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
md5sum: N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar: No such file or  directory
mv: cannot stat ‘N900PVPUCNC5_N900PSPTCNC5_N900PVPUCNC5_HOME.tar’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the md5sum to the file, the md5sum of the file content changes. More usual is to keep the md5sum in a separate file, or change the filename to include the md5sum:

```
mv abc.tar abc.tar.$(md5sum  abc.tar | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

There are files that store a checksum in the file (somewhere in the header, or at the end) This relies on the program that checks this to know where the checksum is and not incorporate it in calculating the checksum itself.

---

You should IMO not use -t on a `.tar` file.

Comment: I tried your command, I think it needs a bit fine tuning. I am adding the output to my original post.